# E[X/Y], iid, show it is greater than 1

Tags: probability, expected-value, iid

X, Y are IID. show E[X/Y] > 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect $X$ and $Y$ are strictly positive random variables. Then using indpendence, Jensen inequality and identical distributions it follows
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{X}{Y}\right]=\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{Y}\right]>\mathbb{E}[X]\frac{1}{\mathbb{E}[Y]}=\frac{\mathbb{E}[X]}{\mathbb{E}[X]}=1.
\end{equation}

Comment: yes, that's right.